# letter of first logical disk (PowerShell)

Tags: powershell

How can I get a letter of first logical disk in PowerShell? I need to assign it to the variable. 
So far I have:

```
$drive = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_volume
```

Comment: Whenever you've got an object in PowerShell and you're not sure what you can do with it, try piping it to `Get-Member` to see what it's got, or just dump it to the console. If you do that here, you'll see that `DriveLetter` looks promising.

Comment: What do you mean by "first" logical disk? Volumes are not intrinsically ordered. Do you mean the one with the drive letter that comes first in the alphabet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you actually want logical disk information you should query `win32_logicaldisk`

```
Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -filter "Drivetype=3"
```

`3` being the *Local Disk*

If you only wanted the "first" you could pipe it into `Select-Object`

```
Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -filter "Drivetype=3" | Select-Object -First 1
```

If you then still needed information from `win32_volume` you could do this

```
$firstDisk = Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -filter "Drivetype=3" | Select-Object -First 1 -ExpandProperty caption
Get-WmiObject -Class win32_volume | Where-Object{$_.DriveLetter -eq $firstDisk}
```

Comment: Sorry. This wasnt meant to be a duplicate.

Comment: no I mean, I just posted a question, I need help with my PS script

Comment: @mario: it's at times like this that I regret that I cannot in good conscience upvote comments just because they make me laugh.

Comment: @Roberto you have to be more specific.. what "letter" do you want? everyone keeps guessing what you're trying to get.

Answer (score 1):

Use this command:

```
Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -ComputerName $pc -filter "Drivetype=3"
```

Depends what else you want to use it with of course, it should give you what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

Just for funs sake here is another proposal:

```
Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem | where {$_.Used -ne $null} | select -First 1
```

Matt´s answer is the way to go though